# What is the proper way to use the async mechanism: timer_start

Tags: vim8, job-control, async

I just started to use Vim 8 and I'm trying to figure out how to use the async mechanism: `timer_start`.

As my understanding, `timer_start` allows us to run a job asynchronously and repeatly.

I have two questions on it:

1. Need I care about the resource issue?

   Saying that I want to start a job, which needs to be executed only once. So I may code like this:

   ```
   timer_start(10, 'MyCustomFunc')
   ```

   Which means that after 10 milliseconds, `MyCustomFunc` will be called only once.

In this case, need I explicitly call the function `timer_stop` to stop this job? If not, will it cause some resource issue? For example, some resource may not be released because of non-calling `timer_stop`?

2. I just read this link: https://laravel-news.com/vim-8-0-is-released and I got this example:

   ```
   let tempTimer = timer_start(4000, function('CheckTemp', ['out']))
   ```

   This link said: `This will call CheckTemp(‘out’) four seconds later.`

   OK, it seems that everything is fine.

   But in the doc of Vim, I got this:

> timer_start({time}, {callback} [, {options}])
>
> Create a timer and return the timer ID.
>
> {time} is the waiting time in milliseconds.
> This is the minimum time before invoking the callback. When the system is busy or Vim is not waiting for input the time will be longer.
>
> {callback} is the function to call.
> It can be the name of a function or a |Funcref|. It is called with one argument, which is the timer ID. The callback is only invoked when Vim is waiting for input.

As my understanding, `{callback}` is a function, which takes one argument, which is the timer ID.

Now I'm confused. In the example above, if I'm right, `function('CheckTemp', ['out'])` is a functor/lambda, which will invoke the function `CheckTemp('out')`. It doesn't seem that there is a function, which takes one argument which is the timer ID.

So what did I misunderstand here?

**About the second question**

With the help of Jake Grossman, I just did a test as below:

```
function! MyTest(...) abort
    echo a:000
endfunction

function! CustomGrep(...) abort
    call timer_start(0, function('MyTest', ['xxx']))
endfunction
    
command! -nargs=? Grep :call CustomGrep(<f-args>)
```

When I execute `:Grep` in my Vim, I can see the output: `['xxx', 18]`. So the job ID `18` is passed to the function `MyTest` as the second parameter.

I can understand that now.

But how about labmda? if I change the function `CustomGrep` as below:

```
function! CustomGrep(...) abort
    call timer_start(0, {-> call(function('MyTest'), ['xxx'])})
endfunction
```

and now if I execute `:Grep` in my Vim, the output becomes `['xxx']`. So where is the job ID in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on Vim Version: 8.2.1537

## Response:

1. A timer's resources will be freed on one of three conditions:

   - the `timer_stop()` function in Vim is called, invoking it's counterpart `stop_timer()` in the C source.<sup>[1](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b06a6d59d12dbd67d55b3c46f6e5547e9103c931/src/time.c#L598-L612)</sup>
   - after invoking the callback function, there are no repetitions left for the timer, upon which `free_timer()` is invoked.<sup>[2](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b06a6d59d12dbd67d55b3c46f6e5547e9103c931/src/time.c#L523-L539)</sup>
   - the timer has encountered an error three times in a row (this is done to prevent Vim from becoming unresponsive/unusable due to error messages).<sup>[3](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b06a6d59d12dbd67d55b3c46f6e5547e9103c931/src/time.c#L526)</sup>
2. `function()` calls can be nested, so even though the the `Funcref` itself is called with a single parameter (the timer ID), it may be a `Partial` created by another `function()` call, binding an arglist or a dictionary to it as well.

### See:

```
:h timer_stop()
:h Funcref
:h Partial
:h function()
```

Comment: For the second question, I don't quite understand what you meant. Let's use the example above: `timer_start(4000, function('CheckTemp', ['out']))`. In this example, IMHO, it will just call the function `CheckTemp('out')`, am I right? I don't konw where the job ID is. In a word, I thought the function must be like this: `CheckoutTemp(jobID)`, which is not at all.

Comment: It will call the function `CheckTemp()`, passing the timer ID as the next argument after any arguments bound to the `Partial` created by your `function()` call. So, presumably, `timer_start(4000, function('CheckTemp', ['out']))` would invoke the function as in `call CheckTemp('out', <timer ID>)`. There are some more examples in `:h function()`, the first is on line 4702 of `:h eval.txt.

Comment: Great. I just re-edited my post. That proved that you were right. But I got another question: if I use `lambda`, instead of `function()`, where is the job ID?

Comment: The timer ID will be returned by the `timer_start()` function. You’ll need to store it like `let timer_id = timer_start(...)`. You can modify the scope of `timer_id` to fit your use.

Comment: It sounded fishy to me that Vim would keep timer entries around and burden the programmer with the need to free them so I took a look. `free_timer()` is also called from `check_due_timer()` after a timer is fired if it doesn't have any repeats remaining.

Comment: @BLayer Oh nice find. I’ll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Also, if it had been required they didn't document it which would have been an egregious mistake. It's hard to imagine they'd make it (especially this long after release)

Comment: Great, I can freely use lambda now.

Comment: creating and allowing a timer object to expire causes a memory allocation/deallocation but does not otherwise permanently consume resources (lambdas also cause extra memory allocation, compared to a function)